# Dynamic field with field_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fields-for

I have a "sell" form and I use fields_for to put information about the products to sell.

Here is my fields_for form :

```
<%= f.fields_for :sellproducts do |c| %>
    <%= c.label :product %> <%= c.grouped_collection_select :product_id, Category.order(:name), :products, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank => true  %>
    <%= c.label :quantity %> <%= c.text_field :quantity, :size =>"5" %><br />

    <%= c.label :cost %> <%= c.text_field :cost, :size =>"5" %>

    <%= c.link_to_remove "Delete" %>

<% end %>
```

I would like to have the "cost" text_field dynamically filled with the value of product.price when the user select the product in the select field but I don't know how to do this. In fact I don't know how to get the value and then put it...

Can anybody help me please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Taking the cost from the form sounds like a very bad idea. Showing it to the customer, on the other end, may be useful, but it's better not to use an input.

Comment: In fact it is used just to have an information, it is not for the customer but for the seller.

Comment: Let me know if the answer below solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of that you can do this, both involving JS.

**Non-Ajax:**
Build your options, and include data-attributes for each product.

```
<option value="<%= product.id %>" data-price="<%= product.price %>"><%= product.name %></option>
```

Then onchange, just grab the selected option, and put it's data-price in the cost input field.

```
$('body').on('change', 'select.products', function(){
    var that = $(this),
      , costInput = that.parent("fieldset").("input.cost"); # Perhaps if you wrap the elements in a fieldset

    costInput.val(that.find('option:selected').val())
});
```

Pros: Data is there
Cons: You will have to manage the "selected" part that comes with the form helpers

**Ajax (better way):**
Add a onchange event that retrieves the price for the product selected.

```
$('body').on('change', 'select.products', function(){
    var that = $(this),
      , costInput = that.parent("fieldset").("input.cost"); # Perhaps if you wrap the elements in a fieldset

     $.ajax({
        url: "products/price",
        data: {id: that.find('option:selected').val()),
        dataType: 'script'
    }).done(function ( price ) {
        costInput.val(price)
    });
});
```

Pros: No need to fuss with the html
Cons: Can't think of any worth noting.